# Render HTML into an AngularJS view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app with one controller and one view, in my view I have a navigation bar with four options, the thing is that I cant create more html files, I need to work all in the index.html file that is under my app folder, in that file I have three tables where I bind some data coming from a WS that I call in three differente functions in my controller file, for example like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered"  ng-if="topTable === 'topCategory'">
 <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="d in data">
    <td ng-bind = "d.Name">
    <td ng-bind = "d.Email">
 </tr>
</table>

<table class="table table-bordered"  ng-if="topTable === 'topBrand'">
 <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="d in data">
    <td ng-bind = "d.Name">
    <td ng-bind = "d.Email">
 </tr>
</table>
```

I hide the firs two and depending on the radio button selection that I have other tables appears.

My issue is that as I mentioned before, my navigation bar has four options where I have three more tables for each option, so I saw something about directives but Im new to angular and I want to know how to render all the html that I have in my current view without losing functionality and allowing the app to render the correct data depending on the selected option of the nav bar.

I really need help on this.

Thanks

Comment: use a router so the controller and template needed are assigned to navigation route used in navbar. To avoid lots of html duplication you could use a directive or use same template each route but with different headings based on route.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Do you have an example or something to look for?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07